# Allow user to share image on Twitter

Tags: image, twitter, share, tweets

Is it possible to have a twitter button that a user can select on a web page and have it populated with an image and a tweet. Then provided they are already logged in, allow them to tweet it?

I know there are various libraries around for doing this to your own twitter account, but I want to let the user preview the image then tweet it.

I can get the user to tweet a phrase, and a link to an image, but I want them to have the image embedded in their tweet.

I have managed to write some back end code to authorise ourselves and push an image up to the upload end point, and extract a media_id for it for us to use. And I was hoping I could use this media_id somehow with the tweet button, but it doesn't seem to allow this.

Is it worth keeping with this idea, or is it not actually possible?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a button doing this already or do you want to code such a feature? Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I'm using C# back end and JavaScript front end. I know there is a twitter share button you can use and you include their JavaScript snippet for it to work. Like I said I can include an image URL but not embed an image in the share window that pops up.

Comment: I do not know if this can be done in pure javascript using Twiiter UI. If you want to do it in the backend you can try Tweetinvi (https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Tweets#publish-a-tweet-with-media).